# Getting Error In BizTalk sever DBNETLIB ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am getting this error once in while in BizTalk event log, has anyone faced this issue?

> Error : "An attempt to connect to Bt BizTalkMgmtDb SQL Server database on server failed. Error: "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.""

No Log is found in SQL Server

Comment: Once in a while, as in sometimes you can connect and sometimes you can not, using the same credentials?

Comment: I would suspect that there is some sort of network connectivity issue.